# VBA - Split STRING Function with startPOS and endPOS

Tags: string, excel, vba, split

I need a function in Excel VBA that will split a string with a START_POSITION and END_POSITION.

Like:

```
function splitxy(text as String, start_pos as Integer, end_pos as Integer) as String
```

Do I need to turn my string to an array and use a loop to get the needed chars, or is there a easier way?

Comment: What is wrong with mid(text, start_pos, end_pos - start_pos +1) ?

Comment: Stupid me... that's whats wrong :) Write it as an answer and I'll give you the points... thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment as answer as requested:

```
Function splitxy(Text As String, StartPos As Integer, _
                                           EndPos As Integer) As String 

  splitxy = Mid(Text, StartPos, EndPos - StartPos + 1)

End Function
```

Comment: does this work if I ask for an end position that's bigger then the size of the string?

Comment: If you check the specification for `Mid` in Help you will find the answer is yes.  `Mid` does what you would want in such situations including returning empty strings if the length is zero.  You can also write `Mid(Text, StartPos)` which will give you the rest of `Text`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Function splitxy(text As String, start_pos As Integer, end_pos As Integer) As String
splitxy = Mid(text, start_pos, (end_pos - start_pos) + 1)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, all numbers that had thousand seperators also had a decimal comma. I was able to solve it this way:

```
Function makeNumber(n As String)
  n = Replace(n, ",", ".")

  If Len(n) - Len(Replace(n, ".", "")) > 1 Then
    Dim dots As Integer
    Dim pos_of_last_dot As Integer
    Dim integral As String
    Dim decimal As String

    pos_of_last_dot = InStrRev(n, ".", -1)
    integral = Left(n, pos_of_last_dot)
    decimal = Mid(n, pos_of_last_dot)
    integral = Replace(integral, ".", "")
    decimal = Replace(decimal, ".", "")
    n = integral & "." & decimal

   End If

   makeNumber = n
 End Function
```